# Searching mySQL database for entry with underscore

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a search function for entries by part number:

`SELECT * FROM parts WHERE PART_NUMBER LIKE '%$searchby%`

Some of the part numbers will have an underscore.  The query above does not find these entries.

Table format:

```
_id   PART_NUMBER     PART_NAME
 1    1234            Plate
 2    1234_1          Bowl
 3    12345           Fork
```

Searching "1234" will return Plate and Fork, but not Bowl.

Upadte:
I wanted to point out that searching PART_NUMBER for 'Bowl' also returns no results.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS which u r using.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM parts WHERE columnName LIKE '%/_%' ESCAPE '/'`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  To be clear, I'm not searching using the underscore.  For example, searching for "1234" does not return "1234_1"

Comment: The values are integer type or string type ?

Comment: @AbhishekaMishra String

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?:

```
declare @string table
    (  stringnumber varchar(30))

insert into @string values ('1234')
insert into @string values ('1234_5')
insert into @string values ('1234_56')
insert into @string values ('12347')

select
*
from 
@string
WHERE  stringnumber like  '1234' or stringnumber like '1234%/_%'  ESCAPE '/'
```

Result:

```
stringnumber
1234
1234_5
1234_56
```

Comment: While it seems like this would work, it does not in my case.  The query still does not return the values with the underscore

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the underscore:

```
$searchby = replace all "_" with "\_"

SELECT * FROM parts WHERE PART_NUMBER LIKE '%$searchby%
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

MySQL recognizes the following escape sequences.

```
\0     An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
\'     A single quote (“'”) character.
\"     A double quote (“"”) character.
\b     A backspace character.
\n     A newline (linefeed) character.
\r     A carriage return character.
\t     A tab character.
\Z     ASCII 26 (Control-Z). See note following the table.
\\     A backslash (“\”) character.
\%     A “%” character. See note following the table.
\_     A “_” character. See note following the table.
```